# Mapping a different icon depending on property value in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

https://codesandbox.io/s/r546o8v0kq

My above sandbox shows basic mapping of an array of items. This forms a list of notes, dates and an icon depending on what type of item it is.

I am working some logic that maps each item to find out what value it is, based on that I assign the value a string to complete the type of font awesome logo.

```
const noteType = _.uniq(notes.map(value => value.intelType));
const noteIcon = [
  `${noteType}`.toUpperCase() == "EDUCATION"
    ? "paper-plane"
    : `${noteType}`.toUpperCase() == "ELIGIBILITY"
    ? "heart"
    : `${noteType}`.toUpperCase() == "GENERAL"
    ? "twitter"
    : null
];
```

If "intelType" has a value of "education" it would return the "paper-plane" string to complete the icon. e.g `fa fa-${noteIcon}`

```
    <List>
      {notes.map((note, index) =>
        note !== "" ? (
          <React.Fragment>
            <ListItem className="pl-0">
              <i class={`fa fa-${noteIcon}`} aria-hidden="true" />
              <ListItemText
                secondary={moment(note.createdAt).format("DD-MMM-YYYY")}
              />
            </ListItem>
            <p>{note.note}</p>
            <Divider />
          </React.Fragment>
        ) : null
      )}
    </List>
```

Its not getting mapped and returning all three values, which does not meet any criteria therefore returns null as requested. I'm a bit stuck as what to do next here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define an object that maps intel type to icon names:

```
const noteIconMap = 
      { "EDUCATION": "paper-plane",
        "ELIGIBILITY": "heart",
        "GENERAL": "twitter",
      };
```

And look it up this way inside the render:

```
<i class={`fa fa-${noteIconMap[note.intelType.toUpperCase()]}`} aria-hidden="true" />
```

Although, beware, if there is a case where `note` can have `intelType` undefined, `toUpperCase` call will throw an error.

Here's a link to working modified sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/ojz2lzz03z

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what's going on with this bit of code:

```
const noteIcon = [
  `${noteType}`.toUpperCase() == "EDUCATION"
    ? "paper-plane"
    : `${noteType}`.toUpperCase() == "ELIGIBILITY"
    ? "heart"
    : `${noteType}`.toUpperCase() == "GENERAL"
    ? "twitter"
    : null
]
```

But it makes more sense to me to store that information as an object and then access the icon type that way.

```
const icons = {
    EDUCATION: 'paper-plane',
    ELIGIBILITY: 'heart',
    GENERAL: 'twitter'
}
```

And then going:

```
icons[noteType]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get an icon in the map for each `note.intelType`. Since you're passing an array of ids, none of the icons is matched, and the result is always `null`.

A simple solution is to create a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) of types to icons (`iconsMap`), and get the icon from the Map using `note.intelType`.

btw - currently `note.intelType` us always uppercase, so you don't need to transform it.

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/j7n32ywv13)

```
const iconsMap = new Map([
  ['EDUCATION', 'paper-plane'],
  ['ELIGIBILITY', 'heart'],
  ['GENERAL', 'twitter'],
]);

class Notes extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  render() {
    const { notes, classes } = this.props;

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <List>
          {notes.map((note, index) =>
            note !== "" ? (
              <React.Fragment>
                <ListItem className="pl-0">
                  <i class={`fa fa-${iconsMap.get(note.intelType)}`} aria-hidden="true" />
                  <ListItemText
                    secondary={moment(note.createdAt).format("DD-MMM-YYYY")}
                  />
                </ListItem>
                <p>{note.note}</p>
                <Divider />
              </React.Fragment>
            ) : null
          )}
        </List>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```